# How do I create a new ForwardingCache?

Tags: java, guava

I can't for the life of me figure out how to create a new ForwardingCache. I can see how I should create a Cache but not a ForwardingCache. What (obvious class) am I missing?

EDIT: I forgot to add that I need this forwarding so my listeners can be notified on a cache put. If there is a better way to perform post-put actions then please leave a comment/answer.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Can't figure out how to create a ForwardingCache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is basic difference of Map and Cache in guava terminilogies. So, in guava Cache, you either provide a way to calculate a value if that is not there or do the stuff on preload.

See here http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Applicability

So, I dont think that your put case will arise or can't see how is that arising?

As for creating ForwadCache. if you can still see/explain further how you can use ForwadingCache, you can basically provide a concrete implementation of ForwardingCache.SimpleForwardingCache http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/cache/ForwardingCache.SimpleForwardingCache.html and the override delegate method, of course use Eventbus there.

But coming back to the original question again, you can very well see that there are removalListeners but no addListener on cache.

Just thinking loud you can use EventBus in case of CacheLoader or get operation itself (your compute logic when the value is not found).

Comment: Thanks. The EventBus seemed a bit of an overkill for what I want to do. Basically, when something is added in my cache I want to check some things in another cache. That's it. However I went and read the event bus description and you're right, it would give me a more generic way of informing my listeners. I'm going to read some more but it looks like EventBus is the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As with all the other Guava Forwarding classes, you extend either `ForwardingCache` or `ForwardingCache.SimpleForwardingCache`, overriding the methods you want to intercept. The choice of which of those two you want to use depends on whether you want to provide your backing `Cache` implementation at construction time or through the `delegate()` method.